# AngularJS $http.post(): returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, http-post

I have a form that needs to POST data to a server wich is located in the same network. When posting this data to the server, it returns `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

I also tried posting to the same `url` using **POSTMAN** and this way seems to be working.

Is the Same Origin policy causing this? Is there any solution to go around that policy?

***Note:** Can not change anything on the server-side, only client-side*

Here is the factory that I use to post data:

```
  app.factory("SendForm", ["$http", "CONFIG", function($http, CONFIG) {
      return {
        sendInfo: function(dynamic, user1, user2, user3, user4, user5, fixed, aux, onSuccess, onError, onFinally) {
          var url = CONFIG.urlSendForm + "?absolute=" + CONFIG.absolute + "&info" + dynamic + "$dyn=" + user1 + "&info2=" + user2 + "&info3=" + user3 + "&info4=" + user4 + "&info5=" + user5 + "&fixed=" + fixed + "&aux=" + aux;
          $http.post(url, {
              headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              }
            })
            .success(function(response, data) {
              console.log("success " + response + data + status);
              onSuccess();
            }).error(function(response, data, status, headers, config) {
              onError(response);

            });
        }
      }
    }]);
```

and this is what I get logged in the shell after posting:

> *OPTIONS http://192.168.5.2:9000/?absolute=1234&info1$dyn=1&info2=1&info3=undefined&info4=undefined&info5=undefined&fixed_info=undefined&aux_info=undefined
>   net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE*

Comment: Same network? Is it same domain?

Comment: Angular's POST mechanisms function slightly different than other javascript. I don't remember the specifics, but I know that for any of my angular projects, I have to use `file_get_contents('php://input')` instead of $_POST. So try something like `$POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);`

Comment: Are you using [**query strings**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for **POST**ing data?

Comment: @Arg0n Yes, its in the same network, my project is in the localhost and the server in another pc.
@charliebrownie Yes im using query strings, is there something when a user doesnt fill a field in the form to return empty like `user1=` instead to appear undefined? want me to add that in the question the html form?

Comment: And why aren´t you posting your `data` in the request body? I encourage you to do it this way: post your form `data` in the body of your request.

Comment: The [**$http.post docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) also expect some data passed into the request: `post(url, data, [config]);` (that you're not passing in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ve a bad argument order

> post(url, data, [config]); [DOC HERE](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

change to

```
var data = {
dynamic: dynamic,
user1: user1,
user2: user2,
.....
.....
}

var config = {
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}

$http.post(CONFIG.urlSendForm, data , config).success(...).error(...);
```

Comment: now this is showed in the browser console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.5.2:9000/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @changez This was kindof what i was asking about in my comment. "Is it same domain?" I guess the answer is no.

Comment: Yes the same origin error ( if you cannot access the server side ) cant be exceeded.... a solution should be the JSONP but anyway the server ve to support it

Comment: The problem you're getting has to do with [**CORS: Cross-origin resource sharing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: The server is recieving data, but repeated like 3 or 4 times in the same request

Comment: How do i made with JSONP to see if the server supports it @Vanojx1

Comment: you need to access the code that create your answer..... without see the code you can just contact who ve created that script

Comment: And if I put the project in the same pc as the server it will work?

Comment: yes if you put everything in the same local webserver it will work

Comment: Tried to put everything in the same project and same thing, do you know if there is anything like the ` header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://' . Yii::$app->params['IP']);` used in php, but javascript based? @Vanojx1

Comment: nope.... that's a security control used by the server.... you cant set it from the client